# Using blueprint as the Apache Camel DSL to describe routes in IBM Liberty

Tags: apache-camel, websphere-liberty, blueprint-osgi

My goal is to get Camel running under IBM Liberty application server using OSGi and be able to describe the DSL (Domain Specific Language) routes in Blueprint.  I am making progress and now have a Liberty environment with Camel installed and configured as OSGi bundles.  When I write a Java DSL Camel app as an OSGi bundle, all works exactly as I might hope.

My last step is to be able to describe my camel routes in Blueprint.  To that end I create a new OSGi bundle and defined a blueprint.xml that looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:camelBlueprint="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint-2.14.1.xsd">

    <camelBlueprint:camelContext>
        <camelBlueprint:route>
            <camelBlueprint:from uri="file:c:/temp/in"/>
            <camelBlueprint:to uri="file:c:/temp/out"/>
        </camelBlueprint:route>
    </camelBlueprint:camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

When I attempt to deploy this OSGi bundle, the IBM Liberty OSGi framework fails to deploy the application with the following errors:

```
[3/2/15 0:42:38:796 CST] 00000035 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.esa.internal.DeploySubsystemAction
A CWWKZ0403E: A management exception was generated when trying to install the application Camel1 into an OSGi framework.  The error text from the OSGi framework is:
Resource does not exist: org.apache.aries.subsystem.core.archive.SubsystemContentRequirement: 
namespace=osgi.identity, attributes={}, directives={filter=(&(osgi.identity=OSGITest1)(type=osgi.bundle)(version>=1.0.0))}, resource=org.apache.aries.subsystem.core.internal.SubsystemResource@7bc2d3bc
```

Unfortunately this is where I am now stumped and stuck.  I believe that IBM Liberty uses Equinox as the OSGi platform and not Karaf but reading the [Camel Blueprint](http://camel.apache.org/using-osgi-blueprint-with-camel.html) docs I seem to understand that Apache Aries is required (which Liberty supplies and uses) and that Karaf isn't a dependency.

My MANIFEST.MF for my test bundle is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: OSGITest1
Bundle-SymbolicName: OSGITest1
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Blueprint: OSGI-INF/blueprint/*.xml
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Export-Package: kolban.osgitest
Import-Package: org.apache.camel;version="2.14.1",
 org.apache.camel.blueprint;version="2.14.1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this message can occur if the resolver can't see the bundle, or there's something wrong with the bundle (typically with the Blueprint).  If the bundle resolves ok when you remove the blueprint, then you need to look at what might be wrong in the blueprint.  If this is the case, I would suspect you don't have the Camel blueprint namespace handler enabled in the runtime.

I hope this helps.

Regards, Graham.

Comment: Given that the error message appears to be quite generic, is there a suggested trace setting or other technique where I would be able to get additional details about the message?  I fully believe that I may not have the environment set-up correctly which will likely mean that I need assistance from the Camel technologists.  My MANIFEST.MF was reproduced in the original question and the complete distribution of the latest Camel was placed in the OSGi internal repository ... so if something  has been omitted ... not sure what it could be yet.